# Bootstrap da modularidade de um grafo em R

Tags: r, grafo

Em [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/589625/comparando-valor-original-com-o-bootstrap#comment1026146_589647) à minha resposta a [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/589625/comparando-valor-original-com-o-bootstrap), é pedido para calcular valores bootstrap da modularidade de um grafo agrupado com o algoritmo [`cluster_louvain`](https://igraph.org/r/doc/cluster_louvain.html). Mas a dificuldade é que por vezes o código tentado dá mais que um valor para a modularidade dos grafos aleatórios. Isso pode ser visto com o código abaixo.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(igraph)
)

# primeiro calcular o valor da modularidade 
louvain <- cluster_louvain(matrixnetwork, weights = NULL, resolution = 0.88)$modularity
louvain
#> [1] 0.3911249

# bootstrap da modularidade louvain
Nperm <- 1e3
set.seed(123)
boot_mod <- replicate(Nperm, {
  randomnet <- rewire(matrixnetwork, with = each_edge(0.5))
  E(randomnet)$weight <- sample(E(matrixnetwork)$weight)
  cluster_louvain(randomnet, weights = NULL, resolution = 0.88)$modularity
})

class(boot_mod)
#> [1] "list"
mean(lengths(boot_mod) > 1L)
#> [1] 0.309
plot(density(boot_mod), main = main)
#> Error in density.default(boot_mod): argument 'x' must be numeric
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-09</sup>

O objeto `boot_mod` é de classe `"list"` porque em cerca de 30% dos casos a modularidade é mais que um valor. E a densidade dá erro.

Como não se pode escolher arbitrariamente um qualquer valor da modularidade, como resolver o problema?

---

## Dados

Os dados são os mesmos dos da pergunta do link acima, com a modificação na minha resposta.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(igraph)
)
### DADOS EXEMPLO ###
valores <- c(1, 5, 3, 8, 2, 9, 3, 2, 3 ,2, 5, 3, 6, 5, 1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5, 6, 5, 7, 1, 2, 
             8, 12, 5, 1, 5, 3, 6, 5, 9, 3,3,4,5,7,8,2,7,8,4,3,1,4,4 )
cor_pequena <- 0.1
matrixnet <- matrix(valores, 7, 7)
matcor <- cor(matrixnet, method = "spearman")
matcor[] <- ifelse(matcor < cor_pequena, 0, matcor)
matrixnetwork <- graph.adjacency(matcor, mode = "undirected", weighted = TRUE, 
                                 add.colnames = NULL, diag = FALSE)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-09</sup>

Answer (score 4):

A solução é gerar os grafos aleatórios e usar outra forma de calcular as modularidades desses grafos.

Primeiro calcular a modularidade do grafo original, `0.2888889`. E ver os clusters do algoritmo escolhido, `cluster_louvain`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(igraph)
)

louvain <- cluster_louvain(matrixnetwork, weights = NULL, resolution = 0.88)
louvain |> membership() -> orig_memb_louvain
orig_mod_louvain <- modularity(matrixnetwork, orig_memb_louvain, resolution = 0.88)
orig_mod_louvain
#> [1] 0.2888889
plot(louvain, matrixnetwork)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-11</sup>

Agora o bootstrap da estatística de interesse. Isso é feito depois de gerar os grafos aleatórios e de calcular a que grupos (*clusters*) pertencem os vértices desses grafos.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(igraph)
)

Nperm <- 1e3
set.seed(123)
boot_net <- replicate(Nperm, {
  randomnet <- rewire(matrixnetwork, with = each_edge(0.5))
  E(randomnet)$weight <- sample(E(matrixnetwork)$weight)
  randomnet
})

boot_memb_louvain <- boot_net |> 
  lapply(cluster_louvain, weights = NULL, resolution = 0.88) |> 
  lapply(membership)
boot_mod_louvain <- mapply(modularity, boot_net, boot_memb_louvain, 
                           MoreArgs = list(resolution = 0.88))

main <- "Boostrap Louvain Modularity"
plot(density(boot_mod_louvain), main = main)
abline(v = orig_mod_louvain, col = "red")
```

[image]

```r
t.test(boot_mod_louvain, mu = orig_mod_louvain)
#> 
#>  One Sample t-test
#> 
#> data:  boot_mod_louvain
#> t = -37.437, df = 999, p-value < 2.2e-16
#> alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0.2888889
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  0.2004505 0.2092601
#> sample estimates:
#> mean of x 
#> 0.2048553
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-11</sup>